# Prove two self-adjoint linear operators T and U on a finite dimensional vector space V are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if TU=UT

Tags: linear-algebra

Hint: Prove that the eigenspaces of T is U-invariant. 
I can prove this hint, but what's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ V = \bigoplus E_i $ be the decomposition of $V$ into eigenspaces of $T$. As each $E_i$ is $U$-invariant, $U$ restricts to $U_i := U|_{E_i} \colon E_i \to E_i$. As $U_i$ is self-adjoint, there is an basis $B_i$ of $E_i$ consisting of eigenvectors of $U_i$ (and hence $U$). As $E_i$ is an eigenspace of $T$, the elements of $B_i$ are also eigenvectors of $T$. Now $\bigcup_i B_i$ is a basis of $V$ constisting of common eigenvectors for $U$ and $T$.

Comment: Oh I know why I got stuck. I forgot Ui is also self-adjoint. Thanks a lot!